# Making a "display: none" to "display: block" with js, makes all divs collide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few radio input and when one of them gets clicked, a div full of some information would appear (which has display: none already and would change to block after clicking).
I have a footer below at the end of page.
when I click on the radio, the div appears but it collides with footer, I want it to stay between the footer and radio but footer stays after radio and collides with appeared div!

I really don't know how to fix it.

```js
document.getElementById("radios1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("eu_listing").style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
#eu_listing {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check-inline mr-3">
  <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="radio" id="radios1" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">EU
            </label>
</div>

<div id="eu_listing">
  <h1>Sorry, Currently we are out of Stock!</h1>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid px-0 bg-dark">
  <div class="container myfooter text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-1 text-center mb-2">
        <a href="">ABOUT</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-1 text-center mb-2">
        <a href="">TERMS</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-1 text-center mb-2">
        <a href="">FAQ</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-1 text-center mb-2">
        <a href="">SELL WITH US</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-1 text-center mb-2">
        <a href="">PRIVACY</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-1 text-center mb-2">
        <a href="">ADVERTISING</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="footer_divider">
    <h3>CONNECT WITH US</h3>
    <div class="my-4">
      <a href=""><img class="socialpics" src="../Images/fb.png" alt=""></a>
      <a href=""><img class="socialpics" src="../Images/insag.png" alt=""></a>
      <a href=""><img class="socialpics" src="../Images/twit.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <p>© 2019 asfaf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expected it to push the footer down as much as space needed but it does not move the footer at all!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to write the script inside `<script></script>` tags.

Next, this div needs to be display none, initially.
`<div id="eu_listing" style="display:none">`

```js
document.getElementById("radios1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("eu_listing").style.display = "block";
});
```

```html
<div class="form-check-inline mr-3">
    <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="radio" id="radios1" class="form-check-input" name="optradio">EU
    </label>
</div>

<div id="eu_listing" style="display:none">
    <h1>Sorry, Currently we are out of Stock!</h1>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid px-0 bg-dark">
<div class="container myfooter text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-1 text-center mb-2">
            <a href="">ABOUT</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-1 text-center mb-2">
            <a href="">TERMS</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-1 text-center mb-2">
            <a href="">FAQ</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-1 text-center mb-2">
            <a href="">SELL WITH US</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-1 text-center mb-2">
            <a href="">PRIVACY</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 px-1 text-center mb-2">
            <a href="">ADVERTISING</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="footer_divider">
    <h3>CONNECT WITH US</h3>
    <div class="my-4">
        <a href=""><img class="socialpics" src="../Images/fb.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img class="socialpics" src="../Images/insag.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img class="socialpics" src="../Images/twit.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <p>© 2019 asfaf</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yea, it is displayed none in css already, forgot to mention it!

Comment: hi @fevid did you tried my solution? what you need next

Comment: they are both written in css and script file, still same result

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly modifying the CSS style of the element, you could add a class of `d-none` or similar to the object you want hidden by default.

CSS

```
.d-none {
    display: none;
}
```

Then in JS you could add and remove the class as needed instead of changing it to `display: block`

```
document.getElementById("radios1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("eu_listing").classList.remove('d-none')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ok managed to fix it by making the footers position: relative then getting the height of appearing div and adding that amount to top: value, so the footer would get lower depending the size of appearing div.

```
document.getElementById("radios1").addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("eu_listing").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("footer").style.top = dheight+"px";

});
```